# find a the span and a basis of polynomial $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+(2a+b)x+3c$

Tags: linear-algebra

I try to solve this question like this,
$u=[1,0,0,0]
,v=[0,1,0,0]
,w=[2,1,0,0]
,t=[0,0,0,3]$

I think that this four vectors is spanning set
and then ı check this four matrices independent or dependent? I find that u,v and t are independent so ı said that they are basis. Is it true or not ? I need help.

Comment: We have $$p(x,)=a(x^3+2x)+b(x^2+x)+3c$$ The space is $3$ dimensional

Comment: dimension is 4 because there is a term which is x^3

Comment: I think that your question might be phrased wrong. The span of a single polynomial $p$ is just $$\text{span} (p)=\{\lambda p : \lambda \in F\}$$ and then the basis of this would just be the polynomial $p$ itself.

Comment: The basis consists of $3$ elements ,$x^3+2x,,$ $x^2+x$ and $1.$